# É possível sincronizar repositórios de código instataneamente?

Tags: git, github, backup, gitlab

Por exemplo: alterar meu código no github e a minha importação no gitlab desse mesmo código, ser atualizado de acordo com minhas alterações no github.

Como se fosse um backup de código, que se atualiza instataneamente.

(No caso do netlify, no qual quando eu mudo meu código no gitlab, ele já se atualiza automaticamente no repositório da hospedagem.)

Answer (score 1):

Talvez usando [git hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks)? Tens esta pergunta similar sobre [como actualizar um segundo repositório git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400104/automatically-copy-pushed-files-from-one-github-repository-to-another) no stackoverflow

Comment: Rapaz, se esse for o único jeito, vai ser complicadinho fazer oO.. Mas obrigado, vou tentar essa solução qualquer hora

Comment: O problema dele parece ser um pouco diferente do teu. Ele fala que a estrutura das pastas é diferente entre repositórios. No entanto, acho que usar hooks vai ser a única forma de conseguires fazer isso.